# Curve Fitting Certain Pixels in an Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel, curve-fitting, polynomials

I have an image, which I turned into a binary image (black and white), using the im2bw function and an automatically determined threshold. I would now like to take a certain region of the image, and fit the pixels to a polynomial. More specifically, I want to fit some of the pixels on the black and white border.I have attached an image with a yellow tracing around the portion of the image for which I would like to do this.

Does anyone know how I would go about this? Should I be using the edge function?

Also, I would like to know if it would be possible to change the coordinate system of the curve if one can be produced? I would like it such that the origin of the polynomial lie at the red dot, or somewhere in the general area.

This is the image I am referencing

[image]

The yellow line is the region I'd like to fit a polynomial under and the red dot is the origin of where the polynomial should be.

The original image looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You would first need to extract out the pixels that are along that boundary.... doing that automatically is a challenge in itself.  If you are to mark these points manually, then it's possible to fit a polynomial using standard regression techniques.  It isn't very clear on how you want to acquire these pixels.  Also, have you tried anything?  StackOverflow is a website where you show us what you've tried, you tell us where it's going wrong and we help you fix problems.  We don't implement things from scratch - we aren't a code writing website.

Comment: @rayryeng 

Ok, how would you suggest I choose the points? I am fine with doing it manually, as long as it is not very laborious. Maybe I could use Matlab's edge detection? I applied it to my image, and it did a fairly good job at determining where the edges were (This is a picture of a platelet btw).

Comment: You can do an edge detection, then crop out a region of interest and find the pixels that are non-zero.  Once you have those, then it's possible to fit a polynomial along those boundary pixels.

Comment: @rayryeng

I will do just that. I actually made a very stupid mistake by not cropping out my area of interest previously. Thank you!

Comment: No problem.  This does sound like an interesting problem... I think I'll attempt to write an answer anyway :)  Do you have the original image without your markings on them?... i.e. without the yellow line and red dot.

Comment: @rayryeng

Yes, here is the original image I  was working with:

http://imgur.com/U0mnXio

Comment: if there was a function fit to the edge, could you annotate what you see it looking like?  and what about that function do you want? parameters/etc/?